# How do I get the keys associated with the minimum value in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

So, I'm working on a bio-informatics course problem-set right now, and have gotten stuck on an algorithm.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out a way to make the last function (`SkewMin`) work, as it's supposed to return only the positions where `Skew` is minimized.

And yes, I know the indexing starts at 0, but I'll add 1 every value in `minimumValues` to adjust, so go with it :)

```
# Example:
# index           :    1 2 3 4  5 6  7 8  9  10 11 12  13
# Genome          =>   A T T C  G G  C C  C  G  G  C   C
# Skew(genome)    => 0 0 0 0 -1 0 +1 0 -1 -2 -1 0  -1  -2
# MinSkew(genome) =>                      9            13
```

Here's the actual code (I removed the code for `Skew`, as it does what I described above perfectly, and I'm not allowed to post working code online, which is also why I'm not going to mention the course name):

```
# MinSkew, uses Skew(genome) to find the positions where Skew is at a minimum.

#EX: Skew("ACGTGCC") gives 0 0 -1 0 0 1 0 -1
#             with   index 0 1 2  3 4 5 6 7
#and MinSkew("ACGTGC") gives the index of the nucletides scoring -1 in genome
#                    result: (2,7).

def MinSkew(genome):

    dictOfSkew = dict()
    skewValues = Skew(genome)
    minimumSkew = 0
    minimumValues = list()

    for i in range(0,len(genome) + 1): 

        dictOfSkew[i] = skewValues[i]
        if minimumSkew > skewValues[i]:
            minimumSkew = skewValues[i]
            minimumValues.append(i)

    return minimumValues
```

Comment: How are `SkewMin` and `MinSkew` related?

Comment: Does `Skew()` return a `list` or a `dict`?

Comment: Skew() returns a list, and the SkewMin, MinSkew part was just an error, sorry about that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your core error is that you never clear `minimumValues` when you find a new min, so the values from previous mins are still around. BartoszKP's answer is fine, but to do it in one pass:

```
    if minimumSkew > skewValues[i]:
        minimumSkew = skewValues[i]
        minimumValues = [i]
    elif minimumSkew == skewValues[i]:
        minimumValues.append(i)
```

Comment: Interesting, I did notice the error, though I had some problems figuring out a work-around.
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in the current form won't work, because filtering (finding only minimum values) and calculating the criteria for filtering (the value of minimum) are interleaved. This simplest fix is to first find the minimum:

```
minimumValue = min(skewValues.values())
```

and only then apply filtering:

```
minimumKeys = [k for (k,v) in skewValues.items() if v == minimumValue]
```

(or `iteritems` for Python 2)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Took some time this morning to go over the code, and found a way to make it work like you did, except I've got zero experience with list generators (I think that's what it's called?) so I did it with a second for loop. 
Your solution is much more elegant, though !

Comment: Checked it out, turns out you accidentally swapped dictOfSkew for skewValues. 
I'm thinking about updating Skew() to give a pre-made dict that gives me positions + values in 1 go...

Comment: @PeterBock Sure, cheers! It's called *list comprehension* btw. :)